# Can't get 1080i output from Intel integrated graphics card (Sandy Bridge) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, integrated-graphics, sandy-bridge

I just bought a Celeron G540 and an MSI H61M-P31 for my HTPC, currently running Ubuntu Precise. Previously, I had used an AMD card -- with some work, I got it to send 1080i output, the only thing my ancient TV will properly support.

As it stands, xrandr detects only 640x480 and 720x480 modes for my display, both of which appear weirdly tiled and obscure much of the picture -- so it's hard to even troubleshoot. I've tried to create new 1920x1080 modelines and load them with --newmode/addmode, but I haven't found a combination that works yet. I suspect the problem has something to do with the fact that I need interlaced output, but I have no clue how to force my card to do that with xrandr or xorg.conf. Is there a way to do this? Or will I have to get a dedicated card with better TV support?